# Get the executable's module in PyKD

Tags: python, windbg, pykd

In [PyKD](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) I can get the executable's process name like this:

```
0:017> !py
...
>>> getProcessExeName()
u'C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\rundll32.exe'
```

and I can get module information with

```
>>> print module("rundll32")
Module: rundll32
Start: 7f0000 End: 7fe000 Size: e000
Image: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe
Symbols: e:\debug\symbols\rundll32.pdb\EFAE0C870C2846EDB63B9A7274CD50422\rundll32.pdb
Timestamp: 4a5bc637
Check Sum: 11cf2
```

**How do I convert from the process name to the module name?**

It's not as simple as extracting the file name, since file names with special characters like `Notepad++.exe` converts to `notepad__` as module name.

Background: I want to automate dump analysis and first I check whether it's my program at all and second I want to check the version of the crashed program for which I need the module information. I want to make it a bit more universal and consider the case that the user renames the executable.

Versions (if that matters): PyKD 0.3.0.25, 32 bit, WinDbg 6.2.9200, Python 2.7.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is actually more insidious than you describe. I've seen where modules loaded using their [short (MSDOS compatible) name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names) are mangled even more.

The only thing I can come up with to answer your question is a bit of a hack. If you assume that the module occupying the lowest address space is the executable's module, then you can use [`lm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `1m` flag to list all modules but only use the first one.

This means you can do:

```
0:001> !py c:\test.py
Module: notepad__
Start: 10000 End: 21c000 Size: 20c000
Image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
Symbols: export symbols
Timestamp: 55ad8d3e
Check Sum: 0
```

Where `test.py` is:

```
from pykd import *

exeModuleName = dbgCommand("lm1m").split('\n')[0]
exeModule = module(exeModuleName)
print exeModule
```

This is still relies on an assumption. Although, I have observed it to be true for all versions of Windows back to NT 4.0, that may not always be the case. For example, I would not be the least bit surprised if Address Space Layout Randomization ([ASLR](http://www.microsoft.com/security/sir/strategy/default.aspx#!section_3_3)) completely broke this assumption for any process linked with it enabled.

---

**EDIT:**

A little bit safer way to do this is to look at the [`PEB`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/source/usermode/undocumented%20functions/nt%20objects/process/peb.html) for the `ImageBaseAddress`. This is the module start address for the base module. You can construct a pykd [`module`](https://pykd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PYKD%200.3.%20API%20Reference&referringTitle=Documentation#module) type out of the base address like so:

```
from pykd import *

peb = typedVar("ntdll!_PEB", getProcessOffset())
exeModule = module(peb.ImageBaseAddress)
print exeModule
```

This should work a bit more reliably, and fail more predicably, were the `_PEB` structure ever to change.

Comment: I don't like `dbgCommand()`, since a) it might be affected by aliases and b) the output may change with a new version of WinDbg. The second approach worked for me and uses PyKD only. That's great!

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yeah, I wasn't happy with it either. The only downside I see with option #2, though, is that you need symbols for `ntdll` so it needs a proper symbol path. Luckily that isn't usually a problem.